# An integral related to Cramer's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, indefinite-integrals

I read on a French math forum that one has  $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log^{2}x}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{\pi^{3}}{8} $. As Cramer's conjecture in its strong form predicts that  $ \lim\sup\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_{n}}{\log^{2}p_{n}}\leq 1 $ , could a sufficiently accurate computation of  $ I : =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{p_{\pi(x)+1}-p_{\pi(x)}}{1+x^{2}}dx $ shed a light on this conjecture ?

Edit : Assume  $ p_{0}=1 $.

Comment: No, it could not.  Even if Cramer's conjecture is false, numbers $n$ with $p_{n+1} - p_n > \log^2 p_n$ are likely to be very uncommon, and contribute very little to the integral.